# Difference between ephem.date(. . .) and ephem.Date(. . .) in PyEphem

Tags: python, pyephem

Is there a difference between behaviour of ephem.date(. . .) and ephem.Date(. . .) in PyEphem? As far as I can see, both have the same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nice thing about python is that you can usually read the source code.

I found my pyephem installed in `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ephem/` 
and in there was the comment:

```
# For backwards compatibility, provide lower-case names for our Date
# and Angle classes, and also allow "Lon" to be spelled "Long".
date = Date
angle = Angle
LongLatCoordinate = LonLatCoordinate
```

so you are right  ephem.date() and ephem.Date() are the same, but Date is preferred.

Comment: Wow thanks :-) @meuh this holds true for python 3 too right.

Comment: I imagine so. I dont have a 3 version, but "backwards compatibility" applies just as much, and there would be no reason to change this. Try to find a similar directory holding pyephem on your machine and look for the comment in the file `__init__.py`

Comment: Yeah it's there :-D Thanks again.